# How to auto refresh a partial view?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

How to auto refresh a partial view?

```
public PartialViewResult Chat(string people)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var model = new MessageVM()
            {                          
                realReceiver = people,              
                messageList = db.messages.Where(x => x.sender == User.Identity.Name || x.sender == people).ToList().Take(30)
            };
            return PartialView("_Chat", model);
```

How to auto refresh this partialview

Comment: You should consider using [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr)

Comment: thanks. i will give it a try.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to test quickly, change your controller action for `Chat` from `POST` to `GET`. Then call it by pasting the address in your browser address bar. You can include the value for `people` parameter like this at the end of the URL:

```
?people=valueForPeople
```

Check the returned HTML and ensure that is what you are expecting. Once you have confirmed the action is returning the HTML you want, then you can change back to `POST` if you prefer. Then use the jQuery code below.

One option is to setup a timer on the client side which will call your controller and then you can do whatever you need with the returned data.

```
window.setInterval(function() {

    // send get request to server
    $.ajax({
    url: '/Chat',
    type: "POST", // or use GET
    data: whateverYourArgumentsAre, // people
    success: function (partialViewHtml) {
        $("#divLt").html(partialViewHtml);
        });
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Something went wrong');
    }

});
}, 5000); // Every 5 seconds, 5000 ms
```

Comment: how can i specific which div i want to be updated in the script you provided? in my case this div <div id="divLt">

Comment: @YangDota see my edit please. Sorry I thought you knew how to do that. It is very important to send some static data to your div first like this `$("#divLt").html("<p>It works</p>");` in the `sucess`. That is just to test that it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Html.Action("Messages","Chat", new { people= "give some data"})

Comment: Please edit your code block with description. Thank you.